# Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty {\frac{\sqrt{a_n \ln{n}}}{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {a_n}$ converges, where $a_n>0\  \forall n\geq 1$. How do I show that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty {\frac{\sqrt{a_n \ln{n}}}{n}}$ converges?

Annoyingly the comparison test fails as $\frac{\sqrt{a_n \ln{n}}}{n}$ is not necessarily smaller than $a_n$ for small values of $a_n$.

I've proven it for the case where $a_n$ is a $p$-series with $p>1$, but I don't know how to prove it in general.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, the conditions mean $(\sqrt {a_n})_{n=2}^{\infty}$ is $\ell^2,$ and so is $(\sqrt{\log n}/n)_{n=2}^\infty,$ so their dot product converges. But that might be using terms and results you haven't covered yet.

Comment: Making Thomas's comment more elementary, let $b_n=\frac{\log n}{n^2}$ and note that $$\frac{\sqrt{a_n \log n}}{n}=\sqrt{a_n b_n}\leq\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}$$ by AM–GM inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n {\frac{\sqrt{a_k \ln{k}}}{k}}\right)^2
=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n{\sqrt{a_k}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\ln{k}}}{k}}\right)^2
\leq\sum_{k=1}^na_k\cdot\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\ln k}{k^2}.$$